# Tool to create a TSQL script from a SQL Server 2008 trace file

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql

Are there any tools available to create an executable tsql script from a SQL Server trace file?

Is there an easy manual way?

Comment: Are you talking about the script to create the trace itself?

Comment: Profiler does it...

Comment: @MrHappy: need the trace definition (what Shawn asked) or about the script to get T-SQL events inside the trace?

Answer (score 3):

You could use [ClearTrace](http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/billg/archive/2009/03/29/ClearTrace-updated-to-support-SQL-Server-2008-trace-files.aspx) by Bill Graziano (free) which cleans up trace queries and allows you to sort/filter the trace files and still have a readable tsql from the trace.

*Courtesy reference of Brent Ozar's presentation on "Using Perfmon and Profiler" at SQL Bits 2010*

Answer (score 3):

ClearTrace is a very nice tool that parses current trace files and shows easy aggregated reports on trace files data. But it doesn't script the trace file definition or T-SQL events.

In case you want to script the trace file definition to run it from a job, then you need to go to **Profiler -> Filer -> Export -> Script Trace Definition - choose the needed SQL Server version**.
The result is a script with all the system procedures needed to create the same trace (on a different server or maybe at a later time, provided that you change some parameters like start/stop time, file names..etc).

In case you want to script the events inside the trace file, then you need to go to 
**Profiler -> Filer -> Export -> Extract SQL-Server Events -> Extract T-SQL events**.
The result is a sql script with all procedures and batches ready to be executed.